# Retrofit SocketTimeoutException - Uploading Image

Tags: android, http-post, retrofit

I'm currently using Retrofit for Android as my network communications. When POSTing to my backend server an image, the server is in the middle of the upload and then retrofit "times out" with SocketTimeoutException.

I have added the OKhttp library as some have suggested and still getting the timeout.

The current img sizes are around 750kb because I have scaled them down.

Is there an appropriate way to changes the amount of time until a timeout for retrofit? Or is there a better way to upload images to a server?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps try changing the timeout with [setReadTimeout](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setReadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) on your OkHttpClient; note that a setting of 0 indicates to never time out.

Bonus: if you need help figuring out an appropriate setting, you can read the [bytes successfully transferred](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) before the timeout from the exception, and also find out the current default read timeout with [getReadTimeout](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#getReadTimeout%28%29).

Comment: Well that did the trick, no more socket timeout issue. But I am running into other items right now. I'll give it a look and if it doesn't relate to this question I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Quick question @Hober, I've seen some people set their Retrofit RestAdatper to use an OkHttpClient and other say you just need the library added to make it work. Any suggestions there?

Comment: @JohnShelley according to source code of Retrofit it uses OkHttpClient by default if it is present on the classpath.

Comment: it doesn't work in my case.. still getting samejava.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout