# Retrofit SocketTimeoutException (and/or http 500 error) on http-POST

Tags: android, http-post, retrofit, socket-timeout-exception

I'm trying to do a POST request to our backend server, but I keep getting SocketTimeOutExceptions or HTTP 500 error. 
And it keeps switching between those two randomly (even with the same values).

*Things I've already tried*

- adding OkHttp library (v2.4.0) for some reason I get the error that it's might not be supported though retrofit says it supports v2.0.0+ [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347898/retrofit-sockettimeoutexception-uploading-image)
- implementing `Callback<Account>` into the class instead of [this](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=8vmjg), it also gave me the http500 more than the newer version
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750650/retrofit-sockettimeoutexception-in-sending-multiparty-or-json-data-in-android), I've added the UrlFactory and OkHttp libraries and followed these steps but then the entire app crashes ([log](http://pastebin.com/1HCNsLYq) & [changes](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=ih2mf))

**Below is simplyfied code**

**SignIn**

```
public class SignIn extends Activity implements Callback<Account>{
    private static final String TAG = "SignIn";
    private ImageButton sign_in_backBtn;
    private TextView sign_in_make_account;
    private Button btn_SignIn;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_in);

        btn_SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_btnSignIn);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_email);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_password);
        initListers();
    }

    private void initListers() {
        btn_SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailAdres = email.getText().toString();
                String passWord = password .getText().toString();
                if(emailAdresValidate == true && passWordValidate == true){
                    Account account = new Account(passWord,emailAdres);
                    login(account);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void login(Account account){
        JppApplication.getService().logIn(account,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void success(Account account, Response response) {
        Log.d(TAG,response.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "login success");
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        Log.e(TAG,retrofitError.getKind().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "login failed");
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public interface Service {
    @POST("/accounts/login")
    void logIn(@Body Account account,Callback<Account> created);
}
```

**Account**

```
public class Account {
    @SerializedName("Email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("Password")
    private String paswoord;

    public Account(String paswoord, String email) {
        this.paswoord = paswoord;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

possible log/error I get

```
05-18 09:41:29.800   26126-2080/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.134.216.25 (port 8017) after 15000ms
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-18 09:41:29.800   26126-2080/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
```

or

```
    05-18 10:04:01.455    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP POST http://10.134.216.25:8017/api/accounts/login
05-18 10:04:01.455    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
05-18 10:04:01.455    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 56
05-18 10:04:01.455    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ {"Email":"Gebruikersam@mail.com","Password":"Paswoord1!"}
05-18 10:04:01.455    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (56-byte body)
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 500 http://10.134.216.25:8017/api/accounts/login (17419ms)
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ : HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Cache-Control: no-cache
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 36
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Mon, 18 May 2015 08:04:18 GMT
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Expires: -1
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Pragma: no-cache
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ X-Android-Received-Millis: 1431936258878
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1431936241463
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
05-18 10:04:18.875    6945-7465/be.kdgdemo D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (36-byte body)
```

Comment: Seems that something wrong with your server. Have you checked it by sending request not from your app?

Comment: I can login through the webapp if that is what you meant.

Comment: does your server use the same api for web app? 500 error is only server-side error.  The problem cannot be on client side. I tried to send request through https://www.hurl.it/ but always getting request timeout. Check the problem on server side

Comment: The connection is through a private vpn so it won't work for outsiders at the moment, the api is the same.
I've done some more testing and it seems that sometimes when I post bad credentials it gives me the 500 code, but 9/10 it just gives me the sockettimeout exception.

Comment: Okay, 500 and sockettimeout exception is a server problems. 500 error occurs only if there is an exception on server-side. Socket timeout exception means that server doesn't respond to your request. Try to check what's going on on server with your requests. May be something wrong with vpn settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so turns out the error was because of the following. Our school used a cheap VPN where the server was running on. I always tested this app by running and debugging it on a physical device instead of running it on an emulator.

You had to use the VPN's app to be able to connect to the server, for some reason the connection went down regularly, so whenever we had a timeout exception we just had to restart the VPN connection through the app and we were sure to not receive any timeout exceptions for about a minute or so.

This is what you get when schools try to cut budgets everywhere..

And of course the HTTP-500 was because of an error in our code obviously :)